# Toggling button based on global control variables

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5

I'm trying to toggle on/off a button based on the value of control variables (`choice1_is_selected` & `choice2_is_selected`), which are defined as global.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton

class duo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,text,choice):
        super().__init__()

        layoutC = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutC.addWidget(QLabel(text))
        options=QComboBox()
        options.addItems(choice)
        options.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        layoutC.addWidget(options)
        self.setLayout(layoutC)

    def text_changed(self, s): 
        global choice1_is_selected,choice2_is_selected
        choice1_is_selected = True

class duoB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,text,choice):
        super().__init__()

        layoutB = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutB.addWidget(QLabel(text))
        options=QComboBox()
        options.addItems(choice)
        options.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        layoutB.addWidget(options)
        self.setLayout(layoutB)

    def text_changed(self, s): 
        global choice1_is_selected,choice2_is_selected
        choice2_is_selected = True

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Reproducible")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Block 1"),0,0)
        text2 = 'Block 2'
        select2 = ['Not selected','first','second']
        widgetcomposite1 = duo(text2,select2)
        layout.addWidget(widgetcomposite1,1,0)
        text3 = 'Block 3'
        select3 = ['Unselected','I','II']
        widgetcomposite2 = duoB(text3,select3)
        layout.addWidget(widgetcomposite2,2,0)
        self.btn_download = QPushButton('Download')
        if (choice1_is_selected == True) and (choice2_is_selected == True):
            self.btn_download.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            self.btn_download.setDisabled(True)

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_download,3,0)

        self.setLayout(layout)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

choice1_is_selected = False
choice2_is_selected = False

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```

What is tripping me is that the code seems to check the conditional statement at the start but not later so it never enables the download option.

Comment: The main problem is that you should *not* use globals, as they create a wrong perception of object dynamics and encourage bad coding style. Use instance attributes instead, or custom signals.

Comment: My experience with OOP is limited so you're probably right but I don't understand what you mean by _they create a wrong perception of object dynamics_. I was also thinking of alternative ways to rewrite the code so using custom signals is intriguing. However, I was wondering if that wouldn't create a bulkier code (considering that the control variables are simply used as flags and nothing else).

Comment: OOP is not perfect, and, yes, it sometimes can result in code that may seem more convoluted than it should or could be. But one of the major benefits is the modularity that allows using objects as interoperable "building blocks" (just like Lego bricks: you cannot put them together in *any* combination, but they are made in such a way that you can build extremely complex things very easily). Using globals in OOP can be "dangerous" as you may lose the ability to know to what that variable refers to, what it can do, what happens when it changes, etc., which is very important for OOP concepts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because your if statement no longer works after execution.
You should call that statement again (using signals, calling the function, etc.).

Here is a possible solution that worked for me:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget, QGridLayout, QHBoxLayout, QLabel, QComboBox, QPushButton

class duo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent, text,choice):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layoutC = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutC.addWidget(QLabel(text))
        options=QComboBox()
        options.addItems(choice)
        options.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        layoutC.addWidget(options)
        self.setLayout(layoutC)

    def text_changed(self):
        global choice1_is_selected,choice2_is_selected
        choice1_is_selected = True
        self.parent().button_is_selected()

class duoB(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent,text,choice):
        super().__init__(parent)

        layoutB = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutB.addWidget(QLabel(text))
        options=QComboBox()
        options.addItems(choice)
        options.currentTextChanged.connect(self.text_changed)
        layoutB.addWidget(options)
        self.setLayout(layoutB)

    def text_changed(self):
        global choice1_is_selected,choice2_is_selected
        choice2_is_selected = True
        self.parent().button_is_selected()

class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Reproducible")

        layout = QGridLayout()
        layout.addWidget(QLabel("Block 1"),0,0)
        text2 = 'Block 2'
        select2 = ['Not selected','first','second']
        widgetcomposite1 = duo(self, text2,select2)
        layout.addWidget(widgetcomposite1,1,0)
        text3 = 'Block 3'
        select3 = ['Unselected','I','II']
        widgetcomposite2 = duoB(self, text3,select3)
        layout.addWidget(widgetcomposite2,2,0)
        self.btn_download = QPushButton('Download')

        layout.addWidget(self.btn_download,3,0)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.button_is_selected()
    def button_is_selected(self):
        if (choice1_is_selected == True) and (choice2_is_selected == True):
            self.btn_download.setDisabled(False)
        else:
            self.btn_download.setDisabled(True)


app = QApplication(sys.argv)

choice1_is_selected = False
choice2_is_selected = False

window = MainWindow()
window.show()

app.exec()
```